# Flink processing records in Process Time or in Event Time sporadically

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have following code:

```
stream1
.connect(stream2)
.flatMap(new MyRichCoFlatMapFunction())
.assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(
                        WatermarkStrategy
                        .<Item>forBoundedOutOfOrderness(Duration.ofSeconds(5))
                        .withTimestampAssigner((event, timestamp) -> event.getTimestamp())
                )
.keyBy(item -> item.getKey()).window(new MyWindowAssigner())
.trigger(MyEventTimeTrigger())
.process(new MyProcessWindowFunction());
```

In addition , I set

```
env.setStreamTimeCharacteristic(TimeCharacteristic.EventTime);
```

But , in my trigger , I see with breakpoint on both functions

```
onProcessingTime() is being called
```

And sometimes

```
onEventTime()
```

What is the reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that when You set `EventTime` as time characteristic, Flink will still trigger processing time triggers, fire processing time timers and generally it will allow You to still use `ProcessingTime` in several places.

This is correct and may be very convenient in specific cases, for example if something goes wrong with Your input source and it doesn't produce any input, You may still use `ProcessingTime` trigger as a safety switch to still close pending windows.

Note, that if Your code is written correctly  this shouldn't cause ANY issues.